# Beginner help at proving two sets are equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I'm a computer scientist who is a complete noob at proofs.

This was a part of my home exercises but I think I failed totally so I'd love to have some advice how I'm supposed to do this. It's about propositional logic.

The question is:

> Let $M$ be the set of all possible valuations. For each propositional formula $A$, define the set
>
> $$[A]=\{v\in M\mid v(A)=1\}.$$
>   That is, $[A]$ is the set of all valuations which make the formula $A$ true. Show that:
>
> $$[A\wedge B]=[A]\cap[B]$$

My proof:

> Let $x∈[A∧B]$. Therefore $x∈A$ and $x∈B$.
>   Let $y∈[A]∩[B]$. Therefore $y∈A$ and $y∈B$.
>   Therefore $x$ and $y$ are equal thus the sets are the same.

I think I skipped over some crucial steps like defining the set but for the love of god I can't understand how these proofs work. If someone could strip away all the magic from this and explain it in a way that a pragmatic programmer could understand it I'd be forever grateful. The abstraction level here is just too great for me to figure out the "syntax".

Like for example I can't understand with what set of rules should I establish my deductions? Intersection of sets I guess is so common property that every mathematician is supposed to know it (?) or do I have to reference the law which I'm this conclusion basing? That would at least make sense to me. Eg. "By the rules of set theory intersection of two sets is x and x". Sure a bit wordy but that would finally clear this thing up for me.

I understand axioms are the core properties of the objects and from which all laws/rules deliver from (?) but is it always somewhat assumed that the reader knows those rules/axioms? I wish I could just run this in my code interpreter to see if it's correct or not... :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're just writing down symbols that don't mean anything.  You say for example, that if $x \in [A \wedge B]$ then $x \in A \cap B$.  That doesn't make any sense.  You mean  $x \in [A] \cap [B]$ but it's not a matter of "syntax" or "magic".  Anyone can write what you did accidentally, but that you can't see what's wrong indicates that you don't understand what the formulas mean.  Can you explain in words what $x \in [A \wedge B]$  means?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the easiest way to show that two sets are equal is to show that each one is a subset of the other.  A common proof format is as follows.

> Let $x\in LHS$.
>     ...
>     Therefore $x\in RHS$.
>     Conversely, let $x\in RHS$.
>     ...
>     Therefore $x\in LHS$.
>     We have shown that $LHS\subseteq RHS$ and $RHS\subseteq LHS$, therefore $LHS=RHS$.

In your case I think you are assuming too readily the relation between $\wedge$ and $\cap\,$.  Try this.

Let $v\in[A\wedge B]$.
Then by definition $v(A\wedge B)=1$.
Therefore $v(A)=1$ and $v(B)=1$.  $(*)$
Hence $v\in[A]$ and $v\in[B]$.
By definition of intersection, $v\in[A]\cap[B]$.
Thus $[A\wedge B]\subseteq[A]\cap[B]$.

In line $(*)$ you may need to fill in some details depending on exactly what you have been taught about valuations.  You will also need to prove $[A]\cap[B]\subseteq[A\wedge B]$.  Give it a try.

Good luck!